# Filtering Data from Json Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was working on this issue for a few hours and was searching online for how to do it. I don't really work with data provided by API's so I'm not too sure on how I should handle and filter this data.

I have a Json file that is served by the server containing this data:

```json
[{
    // Category
    "test": [
        // Page
        {
            "title": "test",
            "showTitle": "Demi",
            "description": "This is a test markdown file",
            "page": "test/test.md",
            "tags": ["test"]
        },
        {
            "title": "test1",
            "showTitle": "Demi",
            "description": "This is a test markdown file",
            "page": "test/test.md",
            "tags": ["test"]
        }
    ],
    "demi": [
        {
            "title": "demi",
            "showTitle": "Demi",
            "description": "This is a test markdown file",
            "page": "demi/demi.md",
            "tags": ["demi"]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to be able to filter for either the `title`, `words in the description`, `tags` or `category`. I'm not sure on how to do this though especially in Typescript which is what I'm using...

How can I filter the data and get the results I'm looking for?

PS. In case it matters this is how I'm fetching the data if you didn't figure already

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/docs`, {method: "GET", headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }})
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                setStatusCode("200");
                return response.json();
            } throw new Error("Documentation data cannot be located.")
        })
        .then(data => setJsonData(data))
}, [])
```

I tried mapping the data in order to split the categories up but since the data isn't local my project seems to be finding it hard to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a search string, such as "demi" and
your top level array was other search results.

This is how you could achieve the data filtering.

```js
const json = [...your_search_result_json];
const searchString = `your_search_string`;

json.map((categories) =>
  Object
    .keys(categories) // get the category names
    .map((category) =>
      categories[category] // page[]
        .filter((page) =>
          page.title === searchString // exact match the title
          || page.description.includes(searchString) // partial match the description
          || page.tags.includes(searchString) // either one of the element exact match
          || category === searchString // exact match the category name
        ) // pages -> pages', with your stated matching requirements
    ) // category[] -> category'[] (quote means filtered), for category => post[]
    .flat() // category[] -> page[]
) // categories[] -> page[][]
.flat() // page[][] -> page[]
```

Comment: It took some trial and error with typing but I finally managed to work it out with a simpler data structure